html2canvas doesn't capture text in textarea in SVG
I am working on an Angular node-based application, the nodes in which are html tables containing <textarea>. When I try to generate project previews using html2canvas, neither the text in <textarea> nor <mat-icons> are rendered, maybe it's the same problem.
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zjkz5q
Here is the expectation/result:


And also the html structure of the component:


please share the minimal reproducible code if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

@NarenMurali sure! Edited the question

Please try to use the below code:
  import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { Node, VflowComponent, VflowModule } from 'ngx-vflow';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #contentContainer>
      <vflow [nodes]="nodes" [background]="{type: 'dots'}">
        <ng-template nodeHtml let-ctx>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <textarea #textArea>Initial Text</textarea>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ng-template>
      </vflow>
    </div>
    <button (click)="capture()">Capture</button>
    <ng-content *ngIf="capturedImage">
      <img width="100%" [src]="capturedImage">
    </ng-content>
  `,
  imports: [VflowModule, NgIf],
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('contentContainer') screen!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('textArea') textArea!: ElementRef;
  nodes: Node[] = [
    {
      id: '1',
      point: { x: 100, y: 100 },
      type: 'html-template',
    },
  ];
  capturedImage: string = '';

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  capture(): void {
    // Update the textarea's value before capturing
    const textarea = this.screen.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea');
    if (textarea) {
      textarea.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    }

    html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement, {
      useCORS: true,
      foreignObjectRendering: true,
    }).then((canvas) => {
      this.capturedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


isn't this the same code as I had (which is not working)? i can't find any differences

@GlebKiva I have edited the code, please check now

Another solution I just found is to use dom-to-image package:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <vflow id="flow" #flow [nodes]="nodes" [background]="{type: 'dots'}">
            <ng-template nodeHtml let-ctx>
                <table style="background: red; padding: 20px;">
                    <tr>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ng-template>
        </vflow>
        <button (click)="captureWithDomToImage()">dom-to-image</button>
        <img [src]="capturedImage" *ngIf="capturedImage">

    `,
    imports: [VflowModule, NgIf],
})
export class App {
    capturedImage: string = '';
    nodes: Node[] = [
        {
            id: '1',
            point: {x: 100, y: 100},
            type: 'html-template',
        },
    ];

    captureWithDomToImage(): void {
        domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('flow')!)
            .then((dataUrl) => this.capturedImage = dataUrl);
    }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

